# Parsing a multi-line data file with Python

Tags: python

What's the best way to go about parsing the following multi-line data file with Python?

```
Police Response: 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM   Incident Desc: Traffic Stop OFC:    Received: 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM
Disp: PCHK  Location: CLEAR LAKE RD&GREEN HILL RD
Event Number: LLS121106060941   ID: 60941   Priority: 6 Case No:
Police Response:    Incident Desc: Theft    OFC:    Received: 11/6/2012 1:43:35 AM
Disp: CSR   Location: SCH BLACHLY
Event Number: LLS121106060943   ID: 60943   Priority: 4 Case No:
Police Response: 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM   Incident Desc: Suspicious Vehicle(s)    OFC:        Received: 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM
Disp: FI    Location: KIRK RD&CLEAR LAKE RD
Event Number: LLS121106060944   ID: 60944   Priority: 6 Case No:
```

Records are always broken up into 3 lines -- lines beginning with "Police Response" and ending with "Event Number". Some fields are often blank.

Comment: I'd say that depends on how consistent the format is and what you're trying to extract

Comment: Shawn, the field names are consistent and they're always present, even if there is no value specified. The values are not consistent, but I'm just looking to treat everything as strings, so far. Ultimately, I'm parsing these multi-line records and inputting them into a database.

Comment: If you have any control over the data you are dealing with, I highly recommend moving away from a fixed width/length format. Any convention (xml, json, yaml, etc.) would serve you much better.

Comment: @RyanGates I do not have control over the data. It is a public feed I have no control over, unfortunately. My eventual goal is to import this data, sanitize it, and provide it as a public JSON feed for others.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I've tried really ugly Perl with really ugly regexes. However, my intent is to switch to Python for as much as I can.

Comment: @Jake I am glad to hear it. I had to speak up, because it made my skin crawl a little bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this should do the trick. I split the data you have into a list of cases each containing there lines of your data. Then I used regular expression spiting to split by the field names. After that I put the list of key value pairs into a dictionary so that it's easy for you to loop through the cases and access any field values using the dictionary. I print out the contents of rows just to show the data structure.

**code**

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

data = """Police Response: 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM   Incident Desc: Traffic Stop OFC:    Received: 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM
Disp: PCHK  Location: CLEAR LAKE RD&GREEN HILL RD
Event Number: LLS121106060941   ID: 60941   Priority: 6 Case No:
Police Response:    Incident Desc: Theft    OFC:    Received: 11/6/2012 1:43:35 AM
Disp: CSR   Location: SCH BLACHLY
Event Number: LLS121106060943   ID: 60943   Priority: 4 Case No:
Police Response: 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM   Incident Desc: Suspicious Vehicle(s)    OFC:        Received: 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM
Disp: FI    Location: KIRK RD&CLEAR LAKE RD
Event Number: LLS121106060944   ID: 60944   Priority: 6 Case No: """

lines = data.splitlines()
cases = ['\n'.join(lines[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 3)]
pattern = '(Police Response|Incident Desc|OFC|Received|Disp|Location|Event Number|ID|Priority|Case No):'
rows = []
for case in cases:
    pairs =  re.split(pattern, case)[1:]
    rows.append(OrderedDict((pairs[i*2], pairs[i*2+1]) for i in range(10)))

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    print '============== {} =============='.format(i)
    pprint(row.items())
```

**output:**

```
============== 0 ==============
[('Police Response', ' 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM   '),
 ('Incident Desc', ' Traffic Stop '),
 ('OFC', '    '),
 ('Received', ' 11/6/2012 1:34:06 AM\n'),
 ('Disp', ' PCHK  '),
 ('Location', ' CLEAR LAKE RD&GREEN HILL RD\n'),
 ('Event Number', ' LLS121106060941   '),
 ('ID', ' 60941   '),
 ('Priority', ' 6 '),
 ('Case No', '')]
============== 1 ==============
[('Police Response', '    '),
 ('Incident Desc', ' Theft    '),
 ('OFC', '    '),
 ('Received', ' 11/6/2012 1:43:35 AM\n'),
 ('Disp', ' CSR   '),
 ('Location', ' SCH BLACHLY\n'),
 ('Event Number', ' LLS121106060943   '),
 ('ID', ' 60943   '),
 ('Priority', ' 4 '),
 ('Case No', '')]
============== 2 ==============
[('Police Response', ' 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM   '),
 ('Incident Desc', ' Suspicious Vehicle(s)    '),
 ('OFC', '        '),
 ('Received', ' 11/6/2012 1:47:47 AM\n'),
 ('Disp', ' FI    '),
 ('Location', ' KIRK RD&CLEAR LAKE RD\n'),
 ('Event Number', ' LLS121106060944   '),
 ('ID', ' 60944   '),
 ('Priority', ' 6 '),
 ('Case No', ' ')]
```

Answer (score 3):

The big question:

What is used to delimit the entries? If there are tabs between entries, that makes it easy, just split each line by tab.  If there always at least two spaces, you can split by that.  If there's sometimes just one space, that complicates things.

Otherwise, it's easy to make a generator/function to spit out three lines at a time, which you can then throw into a function that parses the three lines.  The '3-lines-at-a-time' part of your problem is the *easy* part.

```
def return_3(file):
    return [file.next() for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
data = open('file.dat').read()

re.findall("""Police Response:(.*)Incident Desc:(.*)OFC:(.*)Received:(.*)
Disp:(.*)Location:(.*)
Event Number:(.*)Priority:(.*)Case No:(.*)""", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input data format is consistent, here's how I might approach it:

```
# List of fields. Corresponds to colums and rows in input data.
fields = (
  ("Police Response", "Incident Desc", "OFC", "Received"),
  ("Disp", "Location"),                                    
  ("Event Number", "ID", "Priority", "Case No")
)

# generate pattern based on fields
patterns = [re.compile(":(.*)".join(f) + ":(.*)") for f in fields]
```

Here we generate the search pattern based on a list of fields. This makes it easy to view and update the expected data format.

Using the generated pattern, we can parse the corresponding list of strings into a dict with the field names as keys.

```
def parse_record(lines):
  out = {}
  for f, p, s in zip(fields, patterns, lines):
     out.update(zip(f, [s.strip() for s in p.match(s).groups()]))
  return out
```

For brevity, I've left out error checking but adding some checks will allow us to print a more friendly error message if the input data is not as expected. In particular, assert that `len(lines) == len(fields)` and catch the exception raised when `p.match(s)` returns `None`.

The last piece would be to group the input data by the number or lines for each record. This can be done quite easily using the [`grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Here's an example:

```
for lines in grouper(len(fields), open("input_data.txt"):
  record = parse_record(lines)
  print record["ID"], record["Incident Desc"]  # do something with the dict
```