# How can I directly transfer all my output to csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have this string search program that searches strings inside different text files in a folder and the final output is something like this:

```
File.txt
 Failing test : 101222
    error message: 99898989
 Failing test : 101009
    error message: 2345545

Log.txt
 Failing test : 228765
    error message: 445676
 Failing test : 1909998
    error message: 2333465
```

these outputs are coming from different lists within the program and from 2 functions as well, is there any way that I can just directly copy this whole result to a csv file ?

Comment: Yes thats possible. How should the csv file look?

Comment: basically the same as like the one in the final output just a bit of spacing here and there,  is there a module for the direct copying of the entire output into a csv file

Comment: Its just a matter of parsing then. You need to convert it into a list and you can feed it to the csv module CsvWriter or CsvDictWriter. Something like `[['File.txt',  101222, 99898989], ['File.txt', 101009, 2345545]]`. Json may be a better format, as you could avoid repeating the file name in first column.

Comment: You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295083/parsing-a-multi-line-data-file-with-python/13295622) for ideas on parsing the output. Ignore that the question is closed, it seems fine to me and has usable answers.